# how to get EOD price for a token for the last 30 days

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which sources token prices from multiple exchanges throughout the day, I want to get last updated price at end of each day for all tokens, for the last 30 days. I can use max(date) function with inner join to get prices for each day as below -

```
select tokenid, price, source_exchange, max(datetime) from token_prices sp 
inner join 
(select tokenid, max(datetime) as maxdate from token_prices 
where datetime::date='2022-07-12' 
group by token) as sq 
on sq.maxdate = sp.datetime
where sp.tokenid = sq.tokenid
group by sp.tokenid, price, source_exchange;
```

This gets me the unique EOD price for each token, but only for 1 date at a time. Sample result set below -

```
| Token | Price    | Source        | MaxDate                       |   |
|-------|----------|---------------|---------------------------------|---|
| DOGE  | 0.06     | CoinMarketCap | 2022-07-12   23:51:46.366 +0000 |   |
| BTC   | 19394.74 | CoinMarketCap | 2022-07-12   23:51:46.366 +0000 |   |
| LTC   | 47.82    | CoinMarketCap | 2022-07-12   23:51:46.402 +0000 |   |
| BCH   | 98.32    | CoinGecko     | 2022-07-12   23:51:46.402 +0000 |   |
```

I am trying to get result such as above for last 30 days, however can't figure out a way to get these unique EOD prices without using max(date). So expecting something like this

```
| Token | Price    | Source        | MaxDate                       |   |
|-------|----------|---------------|---------------------------------|---|
| DOGE  | 0.06     | CoinMarketCap | 2022-07-12   23:51:46.366 +0000 |   |
| BTC   | 19394.74 | CoinMarketCap | 2022-07-12   23:51:46.366 +0000 |   |
| LTC   | 47.82    | CoinMarketCap | 2022-07-12   23:51:46.402 +0000 |   |
| BCH   | 98.32    | CoinGecko     | 2022-07-12   23:51:46.402 +0000 |   |
| DOGE  | 0.06     | CoinMarketCap | 2022-07-11   23:58:53.154 +0000 |   |
| BTC   | 19972.05 | CoinMarketCap | 2022-07-11   23:58:53.154 +0000 |   |
| LTC   | 48.77    | CoinGecko| 2022-07-11   23:58:53.154 +0000 |   |
| BCH   | 99.35    | CoinMarketCap | 2022-07-11   23:58:53.154 +0000 |   |
```

Any way to achieve this without using temp tables?

sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6c59d4/3

Comment: Don't tag spam. Just tag the RDBMS you are *really* using.  I have removed all the conflicting tags.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using postgresql, so just added that one back again

Comment: Please, provide us the schema and some sample data so that we can test: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6c59d4/3

Not too clean but I hope this helps. I need the EOD price for each token for each date in the datetime column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, just had to group all tokens by date in the inner join query and then select prices without any grouping

```
select tokenid, price, source_exchange, datetime from token_prices sp 
inner join 
(select tokenid, max(datetime) as maxdate from token_prices 
where datetime::date between current_date-30 and current_date 
group by token) as sq 
on sq.maxdate = sp.datetime
and sp.tokenid = sq.tokenid;
```

I was using the max(date) function and grouping in the outer query unnecessarily!